# Copied XPath doesn't lead to html element when page is refreshed

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath

I've recently been learning how to use XPath. [Here](https://www.yesstyle.com/en/phoneus-wide-leg-jeans/info.html/pid.1097662198) is an example where I wanted the XPath of a specific element; a path to one of the options (any really) in the pop-up menu that appears when you click the size/colour combobox:

[image]

[image]

I've been using the Chrome console to inspect the page, getting the XPath of an element I wanted by either creating one myself or using the 'copy XPath' option provided by the console. In this instance, when I locate the element of the example above, I can copy the XPath but when I open a fresh page (of the same link) and paste this in to the Chrome console I get nothing. Does anyone know why this might be happening? How could I get an XPath that works for this example?

Comment: Well is the content dynamically added? Probably need to trigger a click to get the content to render.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Would it be possible to simulate the click just using XPath?

Comment: no, you would have to fire a click event on the element. Not sure what you are doing exactly to help you out here.

Comment: That's alright. I just wanted to know if I could get the XPath for this pop-up menu with an XPath alone but if it's not possible I'll have to re-think my approach.

Comment: The content is included inside a script block in the page. Again I have no idea what you are actually trying to do so hard to help give you a solution. If you view the source you can see it saved into an objecy ysApp.product and inside of that is an array with productOptions

Comment: Please share the XPath you are using.

Comment: This works but the option menu has to be added to the page first ```//div[@class="md-button md-no-style"]//div[@class="infoCol"]/span```